# How do i convert the list of dicts having common key value pair to a new dict with keys as the common value?

Tags: python

I have this list having multiple dictionaries, but each dictionary has a common key through which I want to create a new Dictionary like below
`list =  [{"local_id":1,"id":29,"name":"Ashish"},{"local_id":2,"id":29,"name":"Boora"},{"local_id":3,"id":30,"name":"Harshdeep"},{"local_id":4,"id":30,"name":"Singh"},{"local_id":5,"id":31,"name":"Deepak"}  ]`

This is the desired result
 `dictionry = { 29:{'details':[{"local_id":1,"id":29,"name":"Ashish"},{"local_id":2,"id":29,"name":"Boora"}]}, 30:{'details':[{"local_id":3,"id":30,"name":"Harshdeep"},{"local_id":4,"id":30,"name":"Singh"}]}, 31:{'details':[{"local_id":5,"id":31,"name":"Deepak"}]} }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) and create the output dictionary

```
result = {}
for item in list:
    result.setdefault(item["id"], {}).setdefault("details", []).append(item)
print(result)
```